# Is inner join performed by default?

Tags: sql, database, primary-key, where-clause

I wonder why it is needed to put the (primary key = foreign key) in a where statement. Tables are related to each other via such criteria. So, why everybody use that in the *where* clauses or *join*s?

I mean instead of

> select a.name, b.name
>   from a,b
>   where (a.fk = b.pk) AND (something = "something")

if one says

> ...
>   select a.name, b.name
>   from a,b
>   where (something = "something")

would it be enough?

Comment: It doesn't happen automatically, you might not actually want that after all.

Comment: Not all tables are related by keys, sometimes you will have a compound key, or you may want to join on something other than the foreign keys.

Comment: Why instead of giving "minus" nobody asks for a clarification!

Comment: When the tables are connected together, it is not necessary. right? it is absolutely useless to put it in a where clause

Comment: Typically, you would use a `join`. This `from a,b` is pretty outdated, as far as I know. Anyway, its default would be an inner join without the constrain (a Cartesian product - all `n` x `m` combinations), not a magical join by keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, not everyone uses foreign keys, unfortunately. Second of all, it shouldn't be assumed that a parent table and child table should automatically be joined via the PK and FK of the respective tables, even though that is probably most common.

The folks on the SQL ANSI committee are pretty smart folks. I'm sure they've thought this all through and decided the current standard is the safest and most robust.

BTW, a very nice thing about Linq is that you don't have to specify joins if the tables have the proper FKs defined. Assuming of course that you're doing inner joins. And assuming you actually want to join on the PK and FK.

Comment: If the tables are related in a proper way (standard way), there would be no need to use that (pk=fk) thing. Right?

Comment: @Computer_guy - What if you didn't want to join the two tables in the 'standard' way?

Comment: You are right. I am talking about the situations that the where clause gets too long. What I am saying is that in the standard way, one should omit those extra information to make that clause more readable, and it wouldn't have effect on the query. Right?

Comment: @Computer_guy - Are you asking if you *can* omit that using the database you are using? Then the answer is no - it will do something else. Or are you asking if that would be a good idea to implement that auto-where in a database? (still no, but that question is off-topic)

Comment: I get why you wanna say. But if we define a relationship in a standard way, then it is not possible to enter data that doesn't follow the relationship rule

Comment: @Kobi - Why no? If the tables are related via (pk = fk) all desirable records of our where clause normally obey that rule. So, why to use it ?

Comment: @Computer_guy - Your question has nothing to do with entering data. FKs take care of data integrity. Your question has to do with querying data. Of course, these are two completely different things.

Comment: @Randy. That's important. When you have a relationship that doesn't allow you to have non-standard data between 2 tables, then every answer of the query will have that constraint in it